# Как убрать вывод элемента массива?

Tags: c#

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.Write("Введите размер массива: ");
        var n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        int[] a = new int[n];
        Console.WriteLine("Элементы массива: ");
        for (var c = 0; c < n; ++c)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} ", a[c] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()));
        }
        int i1 = 0, i2 = 1;
        for (var r = 0; r < n - 1; ++r)
        {
            for (var c = r + 1; c < n; ++c)
            {
                if (Math.Abs(a[r] - a[c]) < Math.Abs(a[i1] - a[i2]))
                {
                    i1 = r;
                    i2 = c;
                }
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("\nИскомые номера: {0} {1}", i1 + 1, i2 + 1);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

При вводе нового элемента, перед ним отображается ранее введённый элемент. Как это исправить?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вам курсор консоли надо подвинуть обратно или что сделать? Поясните подробнее

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Просто не нужно выводить его в консоль)

То есть вместо

```
Console.WriteLine("{0} ", a[c] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()));
```

необходимо

```
a[c] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
```